# Applications of Stone-Weierstrass Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, normed-spaces

For every continuous function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, prove that there exists a sequence of polynomials $p_n$ such that $p_n$ converges to $f$ on $[0,1]$ and for every $x\in [0,1]$, we have $p_1(x)<p_2(x)<\cdots.$

My Trial is to use the stone weierstrass theorem, but then i dont know how to "adjust " the polynomials such that they become strictly increasing, please helps.

Comment: Which function does $p_{n+1}(x) - p_n(x)$ approximate?

Comment: @DanielFischer The zero function...?

Comment: If you let $n\to \infty$. I thought of an arbitrary but fixed $n$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: the difference between $p_{n+1}-p_n$, so i should let $q_n= p_n+ |p_{n+1}-p_n|$, something like that...? sorry for the dumb question...

Comment: Somewhat similar. You need to _construct_ a sequence of polynomials with the desired properties. In that construction, you use Stone-Weierstraß. If you already have $p1,\dotsc,p_n$, with the desired properties so far, how can you find $p_{n+1}$ continuing the sequence? Well, assume you had such a $p_{n+1}$, let $q_n = p_{n+1}-p_n$, and look at what properties $q_n$ must have. Use S-W to conclude there is such a $q_n$, set $p_{n+1} := p_n+q_n$ and move on to the next step - well, no, actually, formulate it abstractly.

Answer (score 1):

We just need to show that for any continuous positive function $f$ on $[0,1]$, there exist a polynomial $q(x)$  such that $0<q(x)<f(x)$ holds for any $x\in[0,1]$ and $\|f-q\|_{\infty}$ is arbitrarily small. In such a way, we can build our approximation sequence by taking $p_1(x)$ as any constant stricly smaller than $\min_{x\in[0,1]} f(x)$, then $p_2$ as $p_1+q_1$, $p_3$ as $p_1+q_1+q_2$ and so on.

Let $m=\min_{x\in[0,1]}f(x)>0$. By the Weierstrass approximation theorem, for any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a polynomial $r(x)$ such that:
$$\| f-r\|_{\infty}\leq\varepsilon.$$
Assuming that $\varepsilon<\frac{m}{3}$, we can just take $q(x)$ as $r(x)-2\varepsilon$. In such a way we have:
$$ 0<m-\frac{2m}{3}\leq q(x)\leq f(x)+\varepsilon-2\varepsilon < f(x),$$
and:
$$\|f-q\|_{\infty}\leq 3\varepsilon $$
that is arbitrarily small, as wanted.

Comment: sorry, but i dont understand what is $q_1, q_2$...

Comment: @chaoli: $q_1$ is the positive polynomial that approximates $f-p_1$ from below. $q_2$ is the positive polynomial that approximates $f-p_1-q_1$ from below and so on.